# Teamviewer without password

Tags: linux, teamviewer

I have a Linux computer with TeamViewer installed, and Windows computer with TeamViewer installed.

I have both computers associated with my account, so I can see them both in my "Computers & Contacts" list.

I can flawlessly access my Windows computer from my Linux one, but I cannot access the Linux computer from the Windows computer because it requests a password.

How can I configure TeamViewer to not request a password on the Linux computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to set it up in connection>unattended access, and save the password. Also, on the main screen is has a box for a personal password. Make sure you don't have it set on your Linux box.
Under computers&contacts, there is a dropdown menu for each system you have saved. Click it and then click the settings cog wheel, you can save the password.

Comment: I saw no cog wheel. Anyway I really do not know how I did it but now it works. Thanks.